# How to get index of an item from nested array

Tags: javascript, angular

How to get the index of an item from the nested array but don't know how deep is nested
 for example
   arr=[a,[b,[c],[d],e],f,[g],h]

Comment: Define index. What should be index of `c`, 2 or 1?

Comment: want to find index of g

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are trying to get the `index` of for example value `g`.

I created a little script that iterates trough the array, and possibly nested arrays, and if found the correct `value` returns the `index`.

Here is a screenshot of the array with the keys that the function `getIndexOfValue` returns.

[image]

```js
var arr = [
  "a",
  [
    "b",
    [
      "c"
    ],
    [
      "d"
    ],
    "e"
  ],
  "f",
  [
    "g"
  ],
  "h"
]

function getIndexOfValue(haystack, needle) {
  
  for(i in haystack) {
    if(haystack[i] instanceof Array) {
      result = getIndexOfValue(haystack[i], needle);
      if(result) {
        return result;
      }
    }
    else if(haystack[i] == needle) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}
var indexOfA = getIndexOfValue(arr, "a");
var indexOfB = getIndexOfValue(arr, "b");
var indexOfC = getIndexOfValue(arr, "c");
var indexOfD = getIndexOfValue(arr, "d");
var indexOfE = getIndexOfValue(arr, "e");
var indexOfF = getIndexOfValue(arr, "f");
var indexOfG = getIndexOfValue(arr, "g");
var indexOfH = getIndexOfValue(arr, "h");
console.log(indexOfA); //0
console.log(indexOfB); //0
console.log(indexOfC); //0
console.log(indexOfD); //0
console.log(indexOfE); //3
console.log(indexOfF); //2
console.log(indexOfG); //0
console.log(indexOfH); //4
```

It might still contain bugs, I created this quickly in a few minutes.

Comment: What editor did you use for the array view (your screenshot)?

Comment: I simply pasted your array into the console (Chrome Developer Tools Console), and opened all nested arrays to view it like on the image.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the full path, you might use an iterative and recursive approach for the nested array.

The result is an array with all indices.

```js
function findPath(array, value) {
    var path = [];

    array.some(function iter(p) {
        return function (a, i) {
            if (a === value) {
                path = p.concat(i);
                return true;
            }
            if (Array.isArray(a)) {
                return a.some(iter(p.concat(i)));
            };
        };
    }([]));

    return path;
}

var array = ['a', ['b', ['c'], ['d'], 'e'], 'f', ['g'], 'h'];

console.log(findPath(array, 'a'));
console.log(findPath(array, 'b'));
console.log(findPath(array, 'c'));
console.log(findPath(array, 'd'));
console.log(findPath(array, 'e'));
console.log(findPath(array, 'f'));
console.log(findPath(array, 'g'));
console.log(findPath(array, 'h'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```